# How can I handle the value of array or data in json file?

Tags: reactjs

I'm making checkbox function using data in json file.
I want to show 'O' and 'X' according to the value called `checked` in json file.

And want `checked` value changed when 'O' or 'X' is clicked.
For this, I tried to make `handleCheck` function but it doesn't work.

May I know which part is wrong and how to modify it?

**App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import dummy from "./database/data.json";

export default function App() {
  const handleCheck = (number) => {
    dummy.state[number].checked !== dummy.state[number].checked;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {dummy.state.map((item, idx) => {
        return (
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              handleCheck(item.id);
            }}
            key={idx}
          >
            {item.checked ? "O" : "X"}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**data.json**

```
{
  "state": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "checked": true
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "checked": true
    }
  ]
}
```

**codesandbox**

> https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-forest-j0cb25?file=/src/database/data.json:0-176

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into some JavaScript syntax issues and React-specific issues.

One of them is that you're modifying the JSON file array directly, and React isn't going to re-render on those changes. A way to fix this would be to use the [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook with your dummy data as the initial state. You can accomplish this like so:

`const [data, setData] = useState(dummy.state)`

Now, we have a `data` variable which corresponds to your dummy data's state array and a `setData` function which will let us set `data` to whatever value we'd like and have React re-render the UI.

The next bit we need to tackle will be to make sure the `handleCheck` function is updating our `useState`'s `data` variable and setting it correctly. We have two big issues right now with this function.

First, you're really close to flipping the `checked` value, but the `o.checked !== o.checked` is doing a comparison instead of setting your variable; basically, the code is asking "is X strictly not equal to X?" [MDN has a great page on what strict inequality is.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_inequality) What we'd like to do is set A.checked to "not A.checked". To fix this, we can do `item.checked = !item.checked`.

Additionally, calling `dummy.state[number].checked` doesn't point to what you probably think it will since your IDs are keys on an object. If `number = 1`, then `dummy.state[1]` actually ends up being the second item in the array, because JavaScript arrays are 0-indexed. Instead, we can update the function like so

```
const handleCheck = (id) => {
  setData(
    data.map((item) => {
      return item.id === id
        ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked }
        : { ...item };
    })
  );
};
```

Now what we're doing is using the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to loop over your `data`, destructure it (arrays are references, and we don't want to mutate the "old" data), and conditionally change the `checked` property based on if the item's ID matches the ID passed into `handleChecked`.

I've forked and updated your [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/answer-to-dguzh-on-stackoverflow-5muh6p) so you can see it all put together in `App.js`.

Comment: Thank you for the details. It works the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to move the json data to a state value and update the state value accordingly and at the end you can push the json data out

```
import "./styles.css";
import dummy from "./database/data.json";
export default function App() {

const [data,setData]=useState(dummy.state)

const handleCheck = (number) => {
setData(state=>{
let newState=[...state]
newState[number].checked = !state[number].checked;
return newState
}
};


return (
<div className="App">
  {data.map((item, idx) => {
    return (
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          handleCheck(item.id);
        }}
        key={idx}
      >
        {item.checked ? "O" : "X"}
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
);
}
```

The data state value have the correct values and you can use them accordingly